# Add values for records that appear more than once

Tags: sql, database

I am querying 2 tables in a database. I want to add the values of the hours_worked field if a user displays on the same day more than once. This is what I have started with:

```
SELECT name, date_worked, hours worked
FROM users u
INNER JOIN records r
ON u.id = r.users_id
.......
```

That's as far as I get. Any help with the SQL syntax on how to do this would be awesome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just aggregate it using `SUM`

```
SELECT name, date_worked, SUM(`hours worked`) AS totalHoursWorked
FROM users u
     INNER JOIN records r
       ON u.id = r.users_id
GROUP BY name, date_worked
```

Comment: Thank you. So here is another question. If I am selecting a date range say from 1/1/2013 to 1/7/2013, how would I add the sum of hours_worked for each user so they don't display for every date. Sorry if that's confusing. I can try to clarify if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: use `BETWEEN`, eg `SELECT name, date_worked, SUM(hoursworked) AS totalHoursWorked
FROM users u
     INNER JOIN records r
       ON u.id = r.users_id WHERE date_worked BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY name, date_worked`